# How do i map through array to get array of object?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array called **data**. How do i extract sub_data? Just need the sub_data part for each object.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Logo'
    sub_data: [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Company Logo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Logo'
      }, 
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Brands'
    sub_data: [
      {
        id: 25,
        title: 'Company Brands'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Brands'
      }, 
    ]
  }
]
```

Example output will get two outputs because there is 2 objects:

```
const subData = [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Company Logo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Logo'
      }, 
]


const subData = [
       {
        id: 25,
        title: 'Company Brands'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Brands'
      },  
]
```

Not very sure how to use the map function just to get sub_data in the correct structure

Comment: `data.find(element => element.id === yourId).sub_data`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I'd use `?.sub_data` in case of not found.

Comment: You can't have 2 outputs from one operation. By 2 outputs do you mean a nested array that contains your desired arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap` to get `sub_data` in one array

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Logo',
    sub_data: [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Company Logo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Logo'
      }, 
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Brands',
    sub_data: [
      {
        id: 25,
        title: 'Company Brands'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Brands'
      }, 
    ]
  }
]

const result = data.flatMap(item => item.sub_data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I haven't been fast enough haha

Comment: haha, you and I have the same thought though. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array with the `sub_data` objects you can just map the original array:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Logo',
    'sub_data'
    : [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Company Logo'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Logo'
      }, 
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Brands',
    sub_data: [
      {
        id: 25,
        title: 'Company Brands'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Website Brands'
      }, 
    ]
  }
]

const mappedData = data.flatMap(obj => obj.sub_data)

console.log(mappedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use the `.forEach` function of javascript.

```
const subData = [];
data.forEach(item => subData.push(...item.sub_data))
```